# How to Print Preview when using a DocumentPaginator to print?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

I'm using a class I've derived from DocumentPaginator (see below) to print simple (text only) reports from a WPF application. I've got it so that everything prints correctly, **But how do I get it to do a print preview before printing?** I have a feeling I need to use a DocumentViewer but I can't figure out how.

Here's my Paginator Class:

```
public class RowPaginator : DocumentPaginator
{
    private int rows;
    private Size pageSize;
    private int rowsPerPage;

    public RowPaginator(int rows)
    {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        int currentRow = rowsPerPage * pageNumber;
        int rowsToPrint = Math.Min(rowsPerPage, rows - (rowsPerPage * pageNumber - 1));
        var page = new PageElementRenderer(pageNumber + 1, PageCount, currentRow, rowsToPrint)
                       {
                           Width = PageSize.Width,
                           Height = PageSize.Height
                       };
        page.Measure(PageSize);
        page.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), PageSize));
        return new DocumentPage(page);
    }

    public override bool IsPageCountValid { get { return true; } }

    public override int PageCount { get { return (int)Math.Ceiling(this.rows / (double)this.rowsPerPage); } }

    public override Size PageSize
    {
        get { return this.pageSize; }
        set
        {
            this.pageSize = value;
            this.rowsPerPage = PageElementRenderer.RowsPerPage(this.pageSize.Height);
            if (rowsPerPage <= 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Page can't fit any rows!");
        }
    }

    public override IDocumentPaginatorSource Source { get { return null; } }
}
```

The PageElementRenderer is just a simple UserControl that displays the data (at the moment just a list of rows).

Here's how I use my Row Paginator

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    var paginator = new RowPaginator(rowsToPrint) { PageSize = new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight) };

    dialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "Rows Document");
}
```

Sorry for the code dump, but I didn't want to miss something relevant.

Comment: see also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322064/how-can-i-produce-a-print-preview-of-a-flowdocument-in-a-wpf-application

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So I got it working after reading [Pro WPF in C# 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599551) (Page 726).

Basically the DocumentViewer class needs an XPS file to present a print preview of it. So I do the following:

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
var paginator = new RowPaginator(rowsToPrint) { PageSize = new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight) };

string tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();

//GetTempFileName creates a file, the XpsDocument throws an exception if the file already
//exists, so delete it. Possible race condition if someone else calls GetTempFileName
File.Delete(tempFileName); 
using (XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(tempFileName, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocument);
    writer.Write(paginator);

    PrintPreview previewWindow = new PrintPreview
                                     {
                                         Owner = this,
                                         Document = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence()
                                     };
    previewWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

I'm creating the print dialog to get the default page size. There's probably a better way to do this.
XpsDocument is in ReachFramework.dll (Namespace System.Windows.Xps.Packaging);

Here's the PrintPreview Window.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFPrintTest.PrintPreview"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="previewWindow"
    Title="PrintPreview" Height="800" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DocumentViewer Name="viewer" 
                        Document="{Binding ElementName=previewWindow, Path=Document}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind just has a Document property like so:

```
public IDocumentPaginatorSource Document
{
    get { return viewer.Document; }
    set { viewer.Document = value; }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can use System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx) in place of Path.GetTempFileName() to get a filename without creating the file.

Answer (score 7):

The following code uses a MemoryStream to do a print preview.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

Package package = Package.Open(stream, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

var uri = new Uri(@"memorystream://myXps.xps");
PackageStore.AddPackage(uri, package);
var xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package);

xpsDoc.Uri = uri;
XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDoc).Write(paginator);

documentViewer.Document = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
```

Remember to use close() and remove package from PackageStore when the print preview is closed.

Answer (score 3):

WPF doesn't come with any built-in Print Preview functionality, if you want to do a print preview, you're going to have to construct it yourself. Fortunately, it's shouldn't be that difficult.

You've already got the pagination code, which creates your `DocumentPage` objects. These objects contain a `Visual`, which you can go ahead and display in your UI.

What you'll end up doing, is paginating your entire document, collecting all the `DocumentPage` objects, then displaying their visuals inside of a scrolling `StackPanel` or something similar. These are the same `DocumentPage` objects that you can then send to the printer.

Comment: This is actually better solution than document viewer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument("filename.xps", FileAccess.Read);
docViewer.Document = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The WinForm code for print preview is:

```
PrintPreviewDialog PrintPreviewDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
PrintPreviewDialog.Document = PrintDocument;
PrintPreviewDialog.ShowDialog();
```

P.s.: The original poster has commented that this is the wrong answer for an WPF application.

Comment: That's the WinForms way of doing it.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I'm leaving this answer here for future searches on c# and print.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a built in way of doing this

Here is how I got it working in NHaml

```
var documentViewHostDialog = new DocumentDialog();
documentViewHostDialog.LoadDocument(load);
documentViewHostDialog.ShowDialog();
```

Where "load" is either a FlowDocument or IDocumentPaginatorSource
and here is the DocumentDialog
http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/source/browse/trunk/src/NHaml.Xps/DocumentDialog.xaml
http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/source/browse/trunk/src/NHaml.Xps/DocumentDialog.xaml.cs

Hope it works for your case.