# How to Print Preview in Wpf?

Tags: wpf, printing, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

i am trying to print all the contents of a UserControl.

So what i need is to Print Preview the records of a DataGrid in WPF?

For printing is easy, we can use the PrintVisual and just send as argument our UserControl (in this case, the DataGrid).

It looks easy to Print, but i can't find anything to do the Print Preview.

Do we have anything in WPF to to this? And how?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related: [How can I produce a "print preview" of a FlowDocument in a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322064/how-can-i-produce-a-print-preview-of-a-flowdocument-in-a-wpf-application)