# Print Preview in wpf

Tags: wpf, flowdocument, documentviewer, print-preview

I have tried document viewer control and flow document control for print preview in wpf.
But it doesn't working in my case.
So how it is possible printpreview in wpf?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but have you looked at my question and answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584551/how-do-i-do-print-preview-when-using-a-documentpaginator-to-print

Comment: If you want any more answer than that, you're going to have to show what you've done and be a bit more specific about "it doesn't work".

Comment: I am not able to find RowPaginator.So can you please explain me how to use this.

Comment: RowPaginator is my own class (which I've put in the question). I don't think you need it. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322064/how-can-i-produce-a-print-preview-of-a-flowdocument-in-a-wpf-application

Comment: Thanks for replying :) In your code snippet I am not able to understand "_parent.FindName("fdsv1")". Is it your another control or something like that?